# BrEng: "pull your finger out", "cock up" and "stuff it" What do they mean?

Tags: meaning, british-english, slang, offensive-language

In the British sitcom, The Thin Blue Line, Detective Grim makes three intelligently crafted sentences, which are given below. What do they mean?

> It's my arse on the line, so you better pull your finger out
>
> It's my arse on the line, and I don't want a cock up
>
> It's my arse on the line, and if you stuff it, I will be red in the face

Comment: You do realise these are all being used as euphemisms and the joke is the duel meaning?

Comment: Ah the Great British double entendre at its finest. If I had awards to give, I would give the writer of this sitcom one.

Comment: @Liam what I understand is that euphemism means "a mild or indirect word or expression substituted for one considered to be too harsh or blunt when referring to something unpleasant or embarrassing." Those sentences do have double meaning, but I am not sure if we can say those are euphemisms.

Comment: *my arse on the line, so you better pull your finger out* i.e. the direct use of the phrase (*pull your finger out* / *work harder*) and the rude version (*pull your finger out of my arse*)...euphemism

Comment: Glance in any general reference for all the information you would ever need on these.

Comment: Liam - the full version is "pull your finger out of *your* arse".  the minor joke here is that it sounds like "out of 'my' arse"

Comment: don't forget "get stuffed!"

Answer (score 44, accepted):

As Jo Bedard mentions in the comment to Sumit's answer, there are sexual overtones (they are too explicit to be called undertones indeed).

The general meaning of all three expressions is that the speaker's reputation and / or career may depend on the outcome of the current project or undertaking and he urges the other person not to contribute to a failure.

*My arse is on the line* is a not-so-polite variation on *my career is on the line*. Something being on the line means it is at risk. A different expression, very visual expression is *my neck is on the block* (which is used when there is an imminent risk of failure) or indeed *my neck is on the line* which roughly means “I am (at least figuratively) risking my neck for this.”

The explicit use of *arse*, meaning one's behind, gives the speaker (or, his script-writer — as detective Grim's character is seemingly unaware of the double entendres in his wordsmithery) the possibility to “enhance” on the imagery involved:

> It's my arse on the line, so you better pull your finger out.

*Pulling one's finger out* (of their behind) means to get into action, to stop sitting around doing nothing useful. The combination with the speaker's arse being the one that is on the line implies that the addressee wasn't having his finger up his own posterior, but that of his boss. That can be seen as another anal reference to the habit some people have to try and please their bosses rather than doing useful work.

> It's my arse on the line, and I don't want a cock up.

At face value, the sentence is simple: my job is at risk, and I don't want a disaster. A cock up is a mess up, a project turning into a disaster.
However, the combination *implies* that we could read the sentence as *It's my arse on the line, and I don't want a penis up that arse*: my behind is at risk at them moment so don't fool around with it.

> It's my arse on the line, and if you stuff it, I will be red in the face.

Again, *stuff it* normally means the same as causing a *cock up*: messing up the situation. The combination reads: *my arse is on the line, if you put something up my arse, you will make me red in the face*. Whether the redness implies a shamed blush or an angry flush because of the (unwanted) intimacy is up to the reader...

I hope it is needless to say that *none* of these expressions are recommended for use in a formal situation, and in most working environments will **not at all** be appreciated, whether said in jest or used as serious encouragement to your colleagues!

Comment: Detective Grim is known for saying things like these while being unaware of the double entendre.   He isn't trying to enhance any imagery. Per [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Thin_Blue_Line_%28TV_series%29), “DI Grim provided much of the humour through his misuse of the English language ... Sometimes oblivious to subtleties, Grim is far more ignorant than he is willing to admit, which he regularly displays through his butchery of English phraseology ... Habib often stifles her laughter at Inspector Fowler's unintentional double-entendres.”

Comment: @jwpat7 If it's not Grim himself, I would assume at least the script writers _are_ aware of adding the extra layers of meaning — I added a remark to that effect. :)

Comment: Adding to the layers, a [cock-up](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/cock-up.html) can be many things, none of them rude.